# Cassandra / C# - Inserting null values on a map<frozen<whatever>>

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I'm having some trouble using DataStax c# Driver with the Mapper extension when I try to insert/update a POCO with a empty IEnumerable (wich is a Map or a List of frozen).

Shouldn't the driver generate tombstones automatically? (I've added insertNulls: true) options on the Insert but I'm still having exceptions:

```
Exception caught: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in Cassandra.dll ("Null values are not supported inside collections")  136.11s     [1732]
```

Here's part of the code (i've resumed the entity properties to make it easier to understand). Everything is mapped (tables and udt's):

Cassandra Schema:

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS maintenancetime (
    id uuid,
    beg int,
    end int
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    maintenancetime set<frozen<maintenancetime>>
);
```

C# Code:

```
public class Bank {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<MaintenanceTime> MaintenanceTime { get; set; }
}

public class MaintenanceTime {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Beg { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

Bank entity = new Bank();
bank.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
bank.MaintenanceTime = null;
bank.Name = "Test";

CassandraConnection.Mapper.Insert<Bank>(entity, true);
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, you can insert a map column and set it to `null` (generating a tombstone), but setting a cell value to a map containing a `null` value for a key is not supported.

For example, in these following queries, a map containing a `null` value is not allowed:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, map_col) VALUES (?, ?)
UPDATE tbl SET map_col = ? WHERE id = ?
```

That is the reason why the driver is preventing it.

When the column is not frozen, you can set an specific map value to `null` for a given key, using the following query (as pointed out by [@doanduyhai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873530/doanduyhai))

```
UPDATE tbl SET map_col[?] = null WHERE id = ?
```

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#collections

Comment: Hello Jorge, as I mentioned on the OP, I can't do the insert with the Mapper extension. However, I can do the insert/update with the cqlsh.

Answer (score 0):

> you setting an specific map value to null is not supported.

It is supported using UPDATE

```
cqlsh:music> create table mm(id bigint PRIMARY KEY, m map<int, text>);
cqlsh:music> INSERT INTO mm(id,m) VALUES(1, {1: 'one', 2: 'two'});
cqlsh:music> UPDATE mm SET m[1]=null WHERE id=1;
cqlsh:music> SELECT * FROM mm;

 id | m
----+------------
  1 | {2: 'two'}
```

I'm using Cassandra 3.4

Comment: That's right, I updated my answer to include this example.

Comment: As i said, problem is with Mapper extension from C# Driver. cqlsh works fine.